# Echo javascript with a php function inside?

Tags: php

Oh boy! I cant get this to work. Any ideas on what the heck I'm doing wrong? Here's the code.

I'm trying to echo the script but use a php function to get the directory of the js file!!

Any help would be appreicated!!

```
echo '<script src="<?php get_some_function();?> . /js/main.js"></script>';
```

I've tried dif scenerios with escaping but cant get this to output correctly.

Comment: echo '<script src="'.get_some_function().'/js/main.js"></script>';

Comment: You cannot embed php code inside php code. especially like that. the embedded code will NOT be executed and will treated as part of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of opening another script tag inside the string, concat the string and echo.  The `<?php` within your string will not be evaluated.

```
echo '<script src="'. get_some_function() . '/js/main.js"></script>';
```

Comment: **Yes all these work!!!** thank you everyone above and below this post!! Darn quotes! LOL!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already in the PHP context, you can simply concatenate the strings, like so:

```
echo '<script src="' . get_some_function() . '/js/main.js"></script>';
```

Using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) looks more cleaner, though:

```
echo sprintf('<script src="%s/js/main.js"></script>', get_some_function());
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple string concatenation:

```
echo '<script src="' . get_some_function() . '/js/main.js"></script>';
```

**Don't forget to properly escape the output of your function!**

Answer (score 3):

try doing this:

```
echo '<script src="'.get_some_function().' /js/main.js"></script>';
```

or this:

```
$value = get_some_function();
echo '<script src="'.$value.' /js/main.js"></script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that any variable echoed in single quotes ( ' ' ), the value of that variable will be not printed, and if a variable is echoed in double quotes ( " " ) it will be printed.

Similar is true for returned data from a function stored in a varaible. If you are using single quotes, then every php code (variable, or a method call of a class) should be concatenated using dot operator ( . , :P ) . If you are using double quotes, then no need to use . .

Like in all above answers, they have used . to append the php function call, your code may be fine as below also (not tested by me, so you will need to do adjustment) :

```
$src = get_some_function();
echo "<script src=$src/js/main.js></script>";
```

But please note that it is a best practice to use single quotes for any kind of html etc echoed in php code, because HTML attributes are using double quotes.

Hope this will help...

Comment: This is wrong. Your code will just display the string as plain text. Did you try it? See [here](https://eval.in/53497).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just updated my answer. Check here now https://eval.in/53504